# Kinect voice control

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

Interesting issue I'm facing, I'm recording a kinect session (saved in a file) and replaying it successfully by triggering the recording or playback via a kinect button. Here is the problem, as soon as I try and do the same thing, but triggering the event via voice control, I get an error where the saved file is being deserialised. Keep in mind the code that both events call are the same. The error says "cannot acces a closed file". Why does it work when I do this via the button press but not via voice control?

Comment: Can you please include the code you use with the button, voice command and reading the audio file?

Comment: I solved this issue by delegating when triggering the event via voice commands